# Regex back reference, what I am missing?

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

I am writing a micro-templating script where parts of a string are replaced with object options. Here is a short example:

```
var person = {name:"Smith",age:43};
var string = "I am {name} and I am {age} years old";

document.write(string.replace(/{([\s\S]+?)}/g,(person['$1']||"")));
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(string.replace(/{([\s\S]+?)}/g
              , function($0,$1){return person[$1]||"";}));
```

​Also in a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5Ftv/)

The second expression works fine, but not the first one. Could anybody explain why? I thought `$1` could be directly used as a back reference within a string.

Comment: I'm not sure how significant they are, but if you click the 'JS Lint' button, you seem to have a few (reported) errors in your JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas interesting...and weird. For peace of mind I did a test with escaped brackets and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1`, `$2`, ..., `$&` can only be used when they're part of a string value passed to `replace`:

```
string.replace(/{([\s\S]+?)}/g, '$1(matched)');
// result: "I am name(matched) and I am age(matched) years old"
```

But, the 1st snippet is effectively:

```
document.write(string.replace(/{([\s\S]+?)}/g,""));
```

That's because `(person['$1']||"")` is not a value that can be passed as-is. It's a property-lookup and logical-or that will be evaluated first and their resulting value -- `""` -- will be what's actually passed to `replace`.

To be able to evaluate an expression *after* you have a match, you have to use a function to delay the evaluation, as you have in the 2nd snippet.

Comment: Understood, the evaluation doesn't happen in the order I thought.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to me, I mean if you look at this:

```
person['$1']
```

You're basically saying "give me the object `$1` inside `person`" which in this case is `undefined`. I guess it tries to evaluate the object before the regex capture group. That's why you have the function replacement and it works, for this circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

`RegExp.replace` method attempts to parse `$n` expressions (as well as `$&` and several others - look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#section_5) for complete list) only within strings. But something like `person['$1']` is not a string - it's an expression which may be (or may be not) evaluated to string. Only after this evaluation the backreference 'markers' will be parsed.

I suppose the callback in `replace` is the only quite normal way to go in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have single quotes around the $1 in the second regex.

Comment: Right, because it is an argument in my function, and this one is working fine.